# Accessing eclipse content through plug in installer in Mac El Capitan

Tags: eclipse, macos, plugins, installation, osx-elcapitan

I need to provide the plug in installer with the path to eclipse, but could not since the only way to explore the content is through showing the package content.

[Image: The window wheres it asks for the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHWpu.png)

[Image: What i find when browsing into the eclipse folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUqcr.png)

Comment: I tried to copy the contents, but obviously won't  work since the installer needs to add stuff to the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by copying the package content and giving the installer, the path to the copy.

Then replacing the original with the copy after the plug in installer made the change on it.